# SSIS Derived Column Datetime Null values

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

Doing CSV file import to SQL database/table.

There is a date column which comes over as "1899-12-30 00:00:00.000".

Date column is Nullable on the database side.

Not sure why it's still showing 1899..

I used different derived expressions and nothing seem to be working.

I want to see Null instead of "1899-12-30 00:00:00.000" in the table/database.

Pls. advice

Comment: Did you try NULL(DT_DATE)?

Comment: ISNULL((DT_STR,10,1252) [DateColumn]) ? "" :([DateColumn])
[DateColumn] == "1/0/1900" ? NULL(DT_DATE) : (DT_DATE)([DateColumn])
ISNULL([DateColumn])? NULL(DT_DATE): [DateColumn]
ISNULL((DT_DBTIMESTAMP)SUBSTRING((DT_STR,30,1252)[DateColumn],1,10)) ? NULL(DT_DATE) : (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)SUBSTRING((DT_STR,30,1252)[DateColumn],1,10)

Comment: None of the above works

Answer (score 2):

I tried to retain Null values as Nulls in the file on Flat file source.

That resolved the issue. Not sure how I overlooked this option..

Answer (score 1):

This is an option:

1. First just load the data into database. Don't worry about 1899-12-30 00:00:00.000.
2. Add a SQL Task and set the value of DateColumn to NULL wherever its "1899-12-30 00:00:00.000". I'm pretty sure you don't have actual 1899-12-30 00:00:00.000 values in your database, so you don't need to worry.

Comment: I can't do an update on PROD table because of Audit issues, that's the problem. Only Inserts..

Answer (score 0):

I was using a Script Component transformation task, and to make my Date column NULL I had to explicitly set its value à la

```
Row.ColumnName_IsNull = true;
```

otheriwse it defaulted to 12/30/1899.